# Google Scripts onEdit to trigger upon selection change in drop down menu changes drop down menu range to another range

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers

I am trying to populate a range with drop down menu on change in selection, once it selected `On Hold` I want to populate that same cell's drop down with a different range from another sheet.
what I want to do is that we have four Options that I have populated using Another sheet named class, I am first populating for initial status their then when the user selects one these four options it will change the populated menu with another range from Class Sheet.
Sheet Link: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1bSkNa4utGjfADkhBsJKBiQt_KYhZMetGrPwei9NjA8k/edit#gid=670281463

```
function onEdit(e) {
 Logger.log(e)
  // If editing mainSheet
  if(spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() == "2022"){
    var mainSheet = spreadsheet.getSheetByName("2022");
   var r = e.source.getRange("A2:A");
    if (r.getColumn() == 1 ) {
      var col = r.getActiveCell().getvalue();
      if ( col =="On  Hold" ) {
         var cell = mainSheet.getRange("A2:A").setDataValidations(rangeRule) =classListSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues() ;
        mainSheet.getActiveCell().setValue(cell);
      }
    }
     var r2 = e.source.getRange("B2:B");
    if (r2.getColumn() == 2 ) {
      var col = r2.getActiveCell().getvalue();
      if ( col =="Cancelled" ) {
         var cell = mainSheet.getRange("B2:B").setDataValidations(rangeRule) =classListSheet.getRange("C2:C").getValues() ;
        mainSheet.getActiveCell().setValue(cell);
      }
    }
  }
 }
```

Comment: I kind of understand what you want but I don't see where your alternate sheets are defined and I don't see where your datavalidation rules are created.

Comment: onSelectionChange will fire when you first select a cell but not after it is edited and onEdit does not fire on a selection change.

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please briefly describe how the code works and what problem it has. Explain what are you trying to do on `var cell = mainSheet.getRange("A2:A").setDataValidations(rangeRule) =classListSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues() ;`(why are you using two `=` in a single code line?)

Comment: My mistake on that part it was going to be var cell =classListSheet.getRange("B2:B").getValues() ;